# [Python]: Matplotlib Navigation Toolbar use setParent

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt5

i have adapted and extended the Matplotlib Navigation Toolbar for my PyQt5 application. However, I have a problem that I have not yet found a solution to.
In the **init** method I originally had following line

```
def __init__(self, figure_canvas, parent = None):
    # ...
    NavigationToolbar.__init__(self, figure_canvas, parent = None)
    self.parent = parent
```

I then received the following warning:

> The parent attribute was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.3 and will be
> removed two minor releases later. Use self.canvas.setParent()
> instead.

Thus I have rewritten the line `self.parent = parent` to `self.canvas.setParent(parent)`

In my **save_figure** method I now want to access the image that is shown in the canvas. Until now I had done this via the line: `fig = self.parent.canvas.figure`. However, this is no longer possible and I get the above warning again. Can anyone help me solve this problem?

PS: This is my first question here, I hope that I have described everything understandably :)

My Function:

```
import PyQt5.QtWidgets as qtw
import PyQt5.QtCore as qtc
import PyQt5.QtGui as qtg

from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

import numpy as np

class MyToolbar(NavigationToolbar):
   optionsImg = qtc.pyqtSignal()
   addImage = qtc.pyqtSignal()
   nextImage = qtc.pyqtSignal()
   prevImage = qtc.pyqtSignal()

   def __init__(self, figure_canvas, parent = None): 
     self.toolitems = (
         ('Home', 'Reset original view', 'home', 'home'),
         ('Pan', 'Pan axes with left mouse, zoom with right', 'move', 'pan'),
         ('Zoom', 'Zoom Image', 'zoom_to_rect', 'zoom'),
         (None, None, None, None),
         ('Previous', 'Previous Image', "back", 'previous_image'),
         ('Next', 'Next Image', "forward", 'next_image'),
         (None, None, None, None),
         ('Add', 'Add Image', 'add', 'add'),
         (None, None, None, None),
         ('Options', 'Axis Options', 'config', 'config'),
         (None, None, None, None),
         ('Save', 'Save Image', 'filesave', 'save_figure'),
         (None, None, None, None),
         )
    NavigationToolbar.__init__(self, figure_canvas, parent = None)
    self.setStyleSheet('background-color: #141E28; color: black;')
    
    self.update_icons(['home', 'pan', 'zoom', 'previous_image', 'next_image', 'add', 'config','save_figure'])
    self.canvas.setParent(parent)
    self.MyCanvas = figure_canvas

 def update_icons(self, iconList):
    
    for i in iconList:
        pm = qtg.QPixmap(r'path\{0}.png'.format(i))
        if hasattr(pm, 'setDevicePixelRatio'):
            pm.setDevicePixelRatio(self.canvas._dpi_ratio)
        icon = qtg.QIcon(pm)
        self._actions[i].setIcon(icon)
    
 def save_figure(self):
    try:
        self.parent.canvas.figure
    except AttributeError:
        return
    
    fig = self.parent.canvas.figure
    files_types = 'Image (*bmp);Image (*.tif); Image (*.png); Image (*jpeg)'
    fileName, _ = qtw.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, 'Save File', '', files_types)
    if fileName == '':
        return
    else:
        fig.savefig(fileName, bbox_inches='tight', dpi = 300)

 def config(self):
    self.optionsImg.emit()    
 def add(self):
    self.addImage.emit()
 def next_image(self):
    self.nextImage.emit()
 def previous_image(self):
    self.prevImage.emit()
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post to provide a full [mre], and also ensure that you're properly [formatting code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) by checking the post preview, as right now there are lots of indentation problems.

Comment: By the way, can't you access the figure by using `self.canvas.figure`?

Comment: Yes, i can access to the figure by `self.canvas.figure`. But I didn't know it would work. That is the solution to my problem, thank you. :)